# Creating a number formatter in Angular 9 on input field

Tags: angular, format, numbers, pipe

Hello im trying to create a number formatter on a input field.

It works great when im typing numbers, but when i type other characters it seems like the NgModel dont care about my changes, and as soon as I type a number again all of the non digit characters disappears again. Can someone help me out?

wanted behaviour ->
input: "dawdhawdhwa", output: " 0kr"

input: "50000", output: "50 000 kr"

input: "5219319231", output: "5 219 319 231 kr"

input: "dawh2133kdaw5", output: "21 335 kr"

Source code:

```
import { Component, Input, PipeTransform, Pipe } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'numberFormat'
})
export class NumberFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: string[]): any {
        if(!value) {
            value = "0";
        }
        value = value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, "");
        return parseFloat(value as string).toLocaleString('sv') + (args ? args[0] : "");
    }
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-input',
  template: `
  <div >
  <input
    [ngModel]="value | numberFormat: [' kr']"
    (ngModelChange)="value = $event"
    type="text"
  />
</div>
  `,
})
export class InputComponent  {
    value: string
  constructor() { 

  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

Comment: The best option to do that is creating an `inputNumber` directive, have you tried that? I don't like (and I don't think it's a good practice) to pipe a `[ngModel]`. In the directive you will `@HostListener` and use your same `transform`. I have a working example here [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-number-directive-comma-format?file=src%2Fapp%2Fnumber.directive.ts), but mine's for pt-BR format.

Comment: Alright i will try that ☺️